# Ошибка при выполнении запроса: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: php

```
Добрый день.
Создал сайт на локальном компьютере- всё нормально.
Перенёс его на хостинг и прописал пароль, пользователя.
Первая у меня срабатывает авторизация, после чего выводит 
Ошибка при выполнении запроса: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)вместо нормальной работы.
И если пользователя(сайта) и пароль ввести неправильно- то возвращается опять на ввод пароля, как и запланировано. Если пароль пользователя сайта правильный- можно "протолкнуть", нажав F5.
Дело в том, что если ввести неправильный пароль базы данных, то этого не будет. Фактически он подключился, но как-то коряво.
Подскажите, что делать в такой ситуации.
Спасибо.
```

Answer (score 1):

Судя по ошибке вы вообще `user` для соединения не указали.